# How to switch from python 2.7 to 3.8 on visual studio code on mac catalina?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

Initially visual studio worked on python 2.7, after the switch to 3.8 as default on mac catalina gives error. How to fix it?

```
MacBook-Pro-Elnar:Python zinsiulyelnar$ python W2exJ.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'W2exJ.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: take a look at this https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

Answer (score 0):

Did you change what `python` pointed to? If so I would undo that change as macOS assumes that `python` points at Python 2.7 as installed by the OS. It will lead to errors like this.